# add closing / with <img> , using regex

Tags: html, regex, tags

```
<img src="images/btn_studyroom.gif" border="0">
```

I'm asp programmer. I need to change all sites for web accessibility .

I want change `<img>` tag

example

`<img~~~>`  to `<img~~~/>`

How to add `/>` using regex?

Comment: Use an html parser. Not a regex

Comment: `<img>` tags are self-closing. Unless you're using XHTML, there's no need to do this.

Comment: thanks @Blender, My web accessbility checker told me that <img> is not enable, so I change it

Comment: @ChangJuPark: That's not correct though. Unless you're using XHTML (post your `<!DOCTYPE>`), `<img>` and `<img />` are identical. You should be adding an `alt` attribute instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, the slash before the > is not "more accessible" but xhtml strict compliant.
I'm not an asp expert, but you can try this kind of thing:

```
String newText = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(<img[^>]+)(?<!/)(?=>)", "\1/");
```

Comment: Good call on the negative lookbehind to validate __this__ image tag doesn't already have a slash. +1

Comment: /\<img+[^>]*[^%\>]/\>/ this is my Regex.